# replace / substitute a tag value from one xml file to another xml using php

Tags: php, xml

Need to replace / substitute a tag value from one xml file to another xml

I need to replace the tag value to another xml file using php

File 1

```
<complete>
  <list>
    <change>hello</change>
    <manage>world</manage>
  </list>
  <list>
    <change>hello1</change>
    <manage>world1</manage>
  </list>
  <list>
    <change>hello2</change>
    <manage>world2</manage>
  </list>
</complete>
```

File 2

```
<complete>
  <list>
    <change>duplicate</change>
    <manage>duplicate</manage>
  </list>
  <list>
    <change>duplicate1</change>
    <manage>duplicate1</manage>
  </list>
  <list>
    <change>duplicate2</change>
    <manage>duplicate2</manage>
  </list>
</complete>
```

O/P

```
<complete>
  <list>
    <change>duplicate</change>
    <manage>world</manage>
    <change>duplicate1</change>
    <manage>world1</manage>
    <change>duplicate2</change>
    <manage>world2</manage>

  </list>
</complete>
```

I need the tag manage to the replaced from 1st xml file to 2nd xml file.

Comment: The question isn't specific enough, please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: have made changes to the body.

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: (1) I would NOT recommend `preg_` at all. Look into `simplexml` or `DOM` for parsing, there are many good examples on this site. (2) Then write some code, edit your question, add that code, and ask specifically for details.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$file1 = file_get_contents("file1.xml");
$file2 = file_get_contents("file2.xml");

preg_match_all('%<manage>(.*?)</manage>%m', $file1, $match, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$xmlmatch = $match[1][0];

$newxml = preg_replace('%<manage>.*?</manage>%m', "<manage>$xmlmatch</manage>", $file2);

file_put_contents("file2.xml", $newxml);
```

Note: Make sure `file2.xml` is writable.

---

After processing `file2.xml` looks like:

```
<complete>
  <list>
    <change>duplicate</change>
    <manage>world</manage>
  </list>
</complete>
```

Comment: Thanks pedro, when i have multiple set's. only the first set tag is replaced in the entire file.
I have edited the body for more clear understanding.
<complete>
  <list>
    <change>duplicate</change>
    <manage>world</manage>
    <change>duplicate1</change>
    <manage>world</manage>
    <change>duplicate2</change>
    <manage>world</manage>
  </list>
</complete>

But  my expected output should be as in the body

Comment: File1 and File2  have exactly the same number of matches?

Comment: the matches are numbered sequentially? like duplicate1 duplicate2, diplicate3

Comment: Same matches are you refering to tags and structure of XML rite. then it si yes

Comment: no.. that was an example. the tag has random generated values. It wont be sequential

Comment: I would like to help you further but I need real files in order to continue, otherwise my work is in vain.

Comment: I guess we are close to the solution, But unfortunately I might not be able to share the file.

The actual intention of the solution is what i had given in the body too. 
I might need one tag value to get replace in another file which has the same tag

To note: The xml structure and xml tags will be same in both the files.

Comment: Adding to this the tag which we are going to replace is unique in each set

Comment: Simply do not use `preg_`-functions for parsing XML. Use a XML parser instead, see my comment above.

Comment: In the original question the OP mentioned the XML file didn't have a valid  XML structure.