# replace or substitute tags from one xml file to another xml file

Tags: php, xml, xslt, command-line

I have two XML files and i'd like to replace/substitute entries from both XML files.

For example below in test1.xml it just lists the name="" which is the only thing that is the same and the other tags are empty. I then have test2.xml with everything except the year, so I'd like to fill the gaps of the tags or replace the information, either using command-line (batch) or php.

test1.xml

```
<game name="test1" image="">
    <description>test1</description>
    <manufacturer></manufacturer>
    <year></year>
    <genre>1985</genre>
    <rating></rating>
</game>
    <game name="test2" image="">
    <description>test2</description>
    <manufacturer></manufacturer>
    <year>1984</year>
    <genre></genre>
    <rating></rating>
</game>
    <game name="test3" image="">
    <description>test3</description>
    <manufacturer></manufacturer>
    <year>1986</year>
    <genre></genre>
    <rating></rating>
</game>
```

test2.xml

```
<game name="test1" index="true" image="">
    <description>test1</description>
    <manufacturer>Activision</manufacturer>
    <year></year>
    <genre>Olympic/Sports</genre>
    <rating>HSRS - GA (General Audience)</rating>
</game>
<game name="test2" index="" image="">
    <description>test2</description>
    <manufacturer>Parker Brothers</manufacturer>
    <year></year>
    <genre>Action</genre>
    <rating>HSRS - GA (General Audience)</rating>
</game>
<game name="test3" index="true" image="">
    <description>test3</description>
    <manufacturer>Atari</manufacturer>
    <year></year>
    <genre>Sports</genre>
    <rating>HSRS - GA (General Audience)</rating>
</game>
```

I had a look at the following code [replace / substitute a tag value from one xml file to another xml using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29872717/replace-substitute-a-tag-value-from-one-xml-file-to-another-xml-using-php) and got it to work however it doesn't keep all the information from multiple tags it just uses the first entries tags for every tag thereafter so say i had 100 entry ... to replace it replaces all the tags with the same information it doesn't keep all the individual information.

Answer (score 0):

A Better approach could be to use xslt. Copy content of selective nodes from test1.

Cheers!